# Spring Control Bus to stop receiving emails

Tags: spring, email, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to filter incoming emails.
I'd like to be able to stop and restart the filtering on demand.

I have tried using the control bus to do so, but when I am stopping the mail inbound channel, the mail receiver keeps listening, and then generating issues when emails are received while the inbound channel is stopped.

I have tried to stop the service activator as well, but this doesn't help.

I have this configuration:

```
<int:channel id="receiveChannel" datatype="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage"/>
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="incomingEmailsAdapter" channel="receiveChannel"
<int:service-activator id="serviceActivator" input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailService" method="handleMail"/>

        MessageChannel controlChannel = ac.getBean("controlChannel", MessageChannel.class);
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@incomingEmailsAdapter.stop()"));
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@serviceActivator.stop()"));
```

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help

Gilles

Comment: Using <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="incomingEmailsAdapter", instead of a imap-idle-channel-adapter works

Comment: Stopping the imap idle adapter should work fine; do you see anything useful in the log?